Try to concatenate videos using FFmpeg Package. My videos concatenate correctly but those that i record from fornt camera rotate 90' in concatenate
Here is my code where I pass a list of image paths that concatenate. I am facing an issue with the front camera video. When concatenated completely some videos rotate 90 degrees.
Future<void> mergeVideos(List<String> videoPaths) async {
    VideoHelper.showInSnackBar('Videos merged Start', context);
    String outputPath = await VideoHelper.generateOutputPath();
    FlutterFFmpeg flutterFFmpeg = FlutterFFmpeg();

    // Create a text file containing the paths of the videos to concatenate
    String fileListPath =
        '${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/fileList.txt';
    File fileList = File(fileListPath);
    await fileList
        .writeAsString(videoPaths.map((path) => 'file \'$path\'').join('\n'));

    // Run FFmpeg command to concatenate videos
    // String command = '-f concat -safe 0 -i $fileListPath -c copy $outputPath';

    String command =
        '-f concat -safe 0 -i $fileListPath -vf "transpose=1" -c:a copy $outputPath';

    VideoHelper.showInSnackBar('command Start', context);
    await flutterFFmpeg.execute(command).then((value) {
      if (value == 0) {
        print("Output Path : $outputPath");
        VideoHelper.showInSnackBar('Videos merged successfully', context);
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => VideoPlayerScreen(
                      videoFile: XFile(outputPath),
                    )));
      } else {
        VideoHelper.showInSnackBar(
            'Error merging videos  ::::: returnCode=== $value ', context);
      }
    });
  }

